# How is an 8p10c connector possible?

Tags: connector, terminology

I thought I understood how modular connector naming worked: npmc, where n is the number of positions and m the number of loaded positions, always loading from the middle out. So for an 8p8c connector, there are eight positions and all of them are loaded with contacts, or for a 6p4c connector there are six positions and the middle four of them are loaded, with the outer two left empty.

But then I encountered [this product category](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/modular-connectors-jacks/366?s=N4IgjCBcoEwOwyqAxlAZgQwDYGcCmANCAPZQDaIMAnACwJwgC6RADgC5QgDKbATgJYA7AOYgAvhKA) on digikey, of 8p10c connectors.

How can you have more positions loaded than there are positions? Where are the other two contacts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears this naming convention is applicable primarily to the jack, not the connector crimped onto the cable. For example, here is an [8P10C connector from CUI devices](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/crj007-mlg-th.pdf) with the following pinout:

[image: CUI Devices CRJ007-MLG-TH Pinout]

[image: CUI Devices CRJ007-MLG-TH Drawing]

As you can see, the connector internally still has 8 pins that contact the modular connector of the cable, but the PCB footprint has 10 pins (not counting the LED pins) where pin numbers 5-6 are center taps for the magnetics.

I haven't found/seen an 8P10C connector which is the same width as a standard 8P but has 10 contacts.

There *is* a wider modular connector named the [10P10C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#10P10C) and also referred to as RJ50, but technically RJxx is a "registered jack" and there appears to be a [lot of historical misuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#Applications) of 8P8C vs RJ45 (but it is rather pedantic).

**Update:**

The [Molex 0432028101](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/432024101_sd.pdf) (and presumably others) definitely shows 10 pins loaded in an 8P-wide jack:

[image: Molex 0432028101 Drawing]

I've not (yet) been able to find an 8P10C connector to compare it to an 8P8C, but I presume the outer connectors are simply added, making the outer housing thinner as needed to accommodate the extra wire pair. With the apparent differences (e.g. the CUI jack above) between these two jacks and existing 10P10C / RJ50 connectors, the potential for confusion and incompatibility seems high.

Comment: The Molex connector datasheet I found had 10 contacts, with size 8 connector. I suppose it proves the terminology can be different with different manufacturers.

Comment: @Justme Ah you're right. I just looked at the [Molex 0432028101](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/432024101_sd.pdf) drawing, and it definitely shows 10 contacts inside the size 8 jack housing. I wasn't able to any 8P10C connectors at Digikey, which I took to support my answer originally.

Answer (score 3):

At least according to Molex connector datasheets, their 8p10c connector has identical size with 8p8c connector but it has two more pins. So 10p8c and 10p10c connector would be wider than 8p8c and 8p10c connectors.

Other manufacturers can mean different things with 8p10c.